# Add style to angular div

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have not worked with Angular 2, but I know css and jquery.

I can't understand this syntax inside component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'sites-stats',
    styleUrls: ['./sites.stats.navbar.component.scss'],
    template: `
<div [sticky]="{'zIndex': 99}">

</div>
`
})
```

I mean `<div [sticky]="{'zIndex': 99}">` With this way my div has `position: fixed;z-index:99`

What should I search to understand this style syntax inside component?

BTW I need to add top to this div, I tried `<div [sticky]="{'zIndex': 99,'top':'2rem'}">` but it didn't work

Comment: If you need to add a static value (i.e. `2rem` which isn't going to change), why not just style it with CSS like you normally would?

Comment: use `[style]="{'z-index': '99','top':'2rem'}"`

Comment: @לבנימלכה thank for response but can you mention how this syntax is named so I can search it in google?

Comment: see my answer please

Comment: About your question, [sticky]="what ever" is pass value to child with input binding https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding, the component sure use this variable to style some div of the component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do it as below:

```
[style]="{'z-index': '99','top':'2rem'}"
```

This calls `style-binding`.

Learn here:https://coursetro.com/posts/code/24/Angular-2-Class-&-Style-Binding-Tutorial

And here:https://alligator.io/angular/style-binding-ngstyle-angular/